# cout behaviour when using ros2 run and ros2 launch

Tags: ros2

I am trying to print to the screen from a node for testing reasons. std::cout is what I am using, I don't want to use RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM for this. When I run my node using ros2 run, I see my prints. When I run my node using ros2 launch, I dont see my cout statements.

Any explination?

Also I have tried and failed to find any ros2 launch (python) documentation anywhere. I was trying to see if there is a output=screen option that I could use to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just add

`output="screen"` as an argument to you launch_ros.actions.Node

I.e. modifying the example from https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Creating-Launch-Files.html

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='turtlesim',
            namespace='turtlesim1',
            executable='turtlesim_node',
            name='sim',
            output='screen'
        ),
    ])
```

If I'm not understanding correctly, please share your launch file.